# I am making a result output system with javascript but the code seems to work with some variables and doesn't work with other variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code works perfectly fine for the first 4 variables but after that i am getting an invalid page response which i created for any invalid entry. but since my entry of url of every variable is there, still it not responding. Can anyone help me with this code. I have also made every html page mentioned in the variable url.

```js
// Define routing:
var validValues = [{
  value: '425769540588',
  url: './something.html'
}, {
    value: '264719964726',
  url: './stud26471.html'
},
{
    value: '327774003000',
  url: './stud32777.html'

},
{
    value: '345102833684',
  url: './stud34510.html'

},
{
    value: '359221005742',
    url: './stud35922100.html'
},
{
    value: '423570687069',
    url: './stud42357.html'
},
{
    value: '439624197820',
    url: './stud43962.html'
},
{
    value: '440176316459',
    url: './stud44017.html'
},
{
    value: '681042208435',
    url: './stud68104.html'
},
{
    value: '729172701174',
    url: './stud72917.html'
},
{
    value: '898871777413',
    url: './stud89887.html'
},
{
    value: '913625248899',
    url: './stud91362.html'
}
];

var $myInput = $('#my-input');
$('#my-button').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent submitting the form already

  // Look for a valid value
  var url = './invalid.html';
  $.each(validValues, function(i, validValue) {
    if ($myInput.val() === validValue.value) {
      url = validValue.url;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // Submit the form
  $('#my-form').prop('action', url).submit();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="title">Hello</h1>

    

    <form class="form-inline" id="my-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="my-input">
    <button type="submit" id="my-button">Go</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: debug it and see why. console.log()  and debugger are your friends.

Comment: I tested it, seems fine. What does it seem to fail with when you test it?

Comment: first four variables are going good for me. but after that the variables are not responding(invalid html page). they all are giving error messages

Comment: Well you  code is running fine here so debug and see what is going on `$.each(validValues, function(i, validValue) {
    console.log($myInput.val(), validValue.value, $myInput.val() === validValue.value); if ($myInput.val() === validValue.value) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    value: '359221005742',
    url: './stud35922100.html'
}
```

I would point out that the fourth one (which I have pasted here) breaks your URL convention, which includes only the first 5 digits of the value. Should it possibly be `./stud35922.html` instead?

Comment: no i named a page like that only.. becz of the same error i tried everything, from changing page name to changing codes. lastly i had to use php and maintain a database .